# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ...` at path "questions"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently building a Node backend with MongoDB / Mongoose and I seem to be having some problem with tying my data together. Specifically, I wish for all users to be able to submit a form (question form) which will then be added to the "questions" collection. In addition to being added to the questions collection, I also need to store a reference to all of the questions a user has answer directly inside of the user object.

Below you can check out my code. Whenever I make a `POST` requestion to `/questions`, it spits out this error. I should note that it successfully adds documents into the questions collection, and each question contains the ID of the user who created it, but the main problem is the **user's `questions` array is not getting updated to include an ID value of submitted questions.**

**Models/User.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),  
      Schema = mongoose.Schema,
      bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');


const UserSchema = new Schema({  
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  profile: {
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String }
  },
  questions: [
  {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Question'
  }
],
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Member', 'Client', 'Owner', 'Admin'],
    default: 'Member'
  },
  resetPasswordToken: { type: String },
  resetPasswordExpires: { type: Date }
},
{
  timestamps: true
});

/** Pre-save of user to database, 
    hash password if password is modified or new 
*/
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**Models/Question.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),  
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Schema defines how questions will be stored in MongoDB
const QuestionSchema = new Schema({
  questionString: String,
  answer: Boolean,
  _createdBy : [
  {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
  }
],
},{
  //user timestamps to save date created as .createdAt   
  timestamps: true
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
```

**Controller/QuestionController.js**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),  
      crypto = require('crypto'),
      Question = require('../models/question'),
            User = require('../models/user'),
      config = require('../config/main');


function setQuestionInfo(request) {  
  return {
    _id: request._id,
    questionString: request.questionString,
    answer: request.answer,
    user: request.user
  }
}

exports.addQuestion = function(req, res, next) {  

User.findById(req.user.id, (err, user) => {
if (err) throw new Error(err);

// We create an object containing the data from our post request
  const newQuestion = {
    questionString: req.body.questionString,
    answer: req.body.answer,
    // in the author field we add our current user id as a reference
    _createdBy: req.user._id
  };

  // we create our new post in our database
  Question.create(newQuestion, (err, question) => {
      if (err) {
        res.redirect('/');
        throw new Error(err);
      }

      // we insert our newQuestion in our posts field corresponding to the user we found in our database call
      user.questions.push(newQuestion);
      // we save our user with our new data (our new post).
      user.save((err) => {
        return res.send('sucess!');
      });
    })
  });
}
```

**Router.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  // Initializing route groups
  const apiRoutes = express.Router(),
        userRoutes = express.Router(),
        authRoutes = express.Router(),
        questionRoutes = express.Router();

  //=========================
  // Auth Routes
  //=========================

  /** ROUTES BELOW WORK FINE -- ONLY DEALS WITH POST TO /questions
   * 


  app.use middle ware sets /auth as auth route (everything goes through /api/auth)
  apiRoutes.use('/auth', authRoutes);
  apiRoutes.get('/dashboard', requireAuth, function(req, res) {  
    res.send('It worked! User id is: ' + req.user._id + '.');
  });


  // Set user routes as a subgroup/middleware to apiRoutes
  apiRoutes.use('/user', userRoutes);

  // View user profile route
  userRoutes.get('/:userId', requireAuth, UserController.viewProfile);

  // Test protected route
  apiRoutes.get('/protected', requireAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.send({ content: 'The protected test route is functional!' });
  });
  // Registration route
  authRoutes.post('/register', AuthenticationController.register);
  // Login route
  authRoutes.post('/login', requireLogin, AuthenticationController.login);
  */

  // Problem Area --> Making POST req to /questions
  apiRoutes.post('/questions', requireAuth, QuestionController.addQuestion);

  // Set url for API group routes
  app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
};
```

Comment: Hi Thomas Greco; that's a _lot_ of code you've pasted in there. Could you try revising it down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: My apologies I didn't realize that I must have added in the model's for each collection twice, but I went through and removed a solid bit of code unrelated to my question. I only included the AuthController and other auth-related stuff to show that the API is working fine (except for this instance :P)

Comment: Can you try  `user.questions.push(question._id);` instead of       `user.questions.push(newQuestion);` ?

Comment: That worked!!! @Veeram thank you so much. do you know the cause of this issue? I thought I needed to encapsulate the new question object inside `newQuestion` and then push that object to my db. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've your schema defined to accept question ids for a user.

```
questions: [
  {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Question'
  }
```

After you save with `Question.create(newQuestion, (err, question)...` the callback attribute `question` has the updated data, one with the `ObjectId`.

Now you add this `ObjectId` value to your existing `questions` array that you got from `findById` on `User` model.

```
user.questions.push(question._id);
```

Mongoose will use the `questionId` to fill your question object when you use `populate` on questions array, but thats part for retrieving information.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!